# String comparison with wildcard in batch file

Tags: batch-file, wildcards

My script do not work with wildcards (IF function)! Log.txt is a List of filenames, some of them should be copied: (IF exclusion==filename copy) the rest (else echo *.html)

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (./Log.txt) do (
IF /i %excl1%==%%a set copy=1
IF /i %excl2%==%%a set copy=1
IF /i %excl3%==%%a set copy=1 
IF defined copy (
    echo "%source%\%%a"
    echo "%savedir%\%%a"
    copy "%source%\%%a" "%savedir%\%%a"
    ) else (
    echo "<p><a href=%savedir%\%%a>%%a</a></p>" >> %htmlfile%)
set copy=
```

)

Ideas to solve the problem?

Comment: Use [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) with it's (limited) regex capabilities and either check errorlevel or use conditional execution.

Comment: Did you want that `set copy=` at the end to ask for user input? if so I can add it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

without changing too much:

```
@echo off

set "dir=C:\your\directory\Log.txt"
set "htmlfile=C:\your\html\file.txt"
set "source=C:\your\source"
set "savedir=C:\your\saved"

set "excl1=firstexclusion"
set "excl2=secondexclusion"
set "excl3=thirdexclusion"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%A in (%dir%) do (
    set "file=%%A"
    IF /i !file! == %excl1% (
    set copy=1
    echo "%source%\!file!"
    echo "%savedir%\!file!"
    echo "%source%\!file!" "%savedir%\!file!") ELSE (IF /i !file! == %excl2% (
    set copy=1
    echo "%source%\!file!"
    echo "%savedir%\!file!"
    echo "%source%\!file!" "%savedir%\!file!") ELSE (IF /i !file! == %excl3% (
    set copy=1
    echo "%source%\!file!"
    echo "%savedir%\!file!"
    echo "%source%\!file!" "%savedir%\!file!"
    ) ELSE (
    echo "<p><a href=%savedir%\!file!>!file!</a></p>" >> %htmlfile%
    )))
)
```

First we'll enable delayed expansion so we can use `%%A` as a variable `!file!` throughout the loop - then it's just a matter of getting the `IF`/`ELSE` formatting right. Hopefully this does what you want.